# With PayPal REST API, when do payment, how can I input setTotal() parameter if several items has different currency?

Tags: php, rest, api, paypal, payment

I am using PayPal REST API - http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html

When payment, we should input total amount with Amount::setTotal() like this:

```
$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency("USD")
    ->setTotal(20)
    ->setDetails($details);
```

Let's say there are several items.

If those all have same currency, we can input total price from calculating sum of them.

But if those are different currency, how can I do?

I should calculate from currency exchange rate and sum?

or any good idea?

Thanks much to anyone help.

Comment: i dont believe you can, i know no payment gateway that will allow this.

Comment: Just make a recalculated price to the final currency, in this case USD.

Comment: Really, recalculating manually to the final currency is the only way?